# arduino to ESP8266 get httpclient problem

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-httpclient

i use [httpclient](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HttpClient) lib in Arduino IDE, but there is no valid respond in monitor and it doesn't work well! it's very simple code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <HttpClient.h>

#define RX 10
#define TX 11

String AP = "SSID";
String PASS = "password";

SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
//  Serial.println("Serial init");
  esp8266.begin(115200);

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  HttpClient client;
  client.get("http://server-address/led.txt"); // just 1 or 0

  while (client.available()) {
    char led = client.read();
//    Serial.println("=> "+led);

    if(led == '1') {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
    } else {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
    }

    delay(1500);

  }

  Serial.flush();
  delay(1500);
}
```

sample example i use [link](https://medium.com/@cgrant/using-the-esp8266-wifi-module-with-arduino-uno-publishing-to-thingspeak-99fc77122e82)

image [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1000/1*Ba6XvjbrufKEN66Fe77tTg.jpeg)

tools: arduino uno, esp8266, breadboard, one led

Comment: What use of Bridge -library? It is planned to work with arduino Yún to communicate with 32u4 and AR9331 and it uses hardware serial (Serial1 class in arduino). You are missing all AT - commands to tell ESP8266 what you want to do, sample is found in the link you posted. You can't make HTTP GET-request without connecting to network first.

Answer (score 0):

try your code using the ESP8266Webserver.h library you can also check the code sample from [here](https://github.com/ncdcommunity/SHT31-temperature-and-humidity/blob/master/espThings.ino)